# Layout or AdapterView larger than screen with absolute positioning of views inside

Tags: android

For an augmented reality application, I need to have a Layout or an AdapterView that would be larger (both width and height) than the screen, in which I could set TextViews by absolute position and that would scroll when moving the device (according to the sensors data);

I am thinking of several solutions:

- Use a RelativeLayout with fixed size in pixels, nested inside a ScrollView and an HorizontalScrollView. In this RelativeLayout I could set the absolute position of the TextViews with the margin values.
- Extend AdaptaterView to have a kind of View with fixed size in pixels allowing to set the absolute position of its children.

But after many tests, I am not sure if any of these solution is good. And I did not manage to get an AdapterView with absolute positioning inside. Any idea ?

Thanks.